# Why can't we directly reference a memory address using the esp register?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

The following is an x86 assembly program meant to be assembled by NASM under 64-bit CentOS over a remote terminal which works absolutely fine when used along with a C program.

```
section .data
section .text
        global  strlen

strlen:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp                ; obtain the address of the
        mov     eax, DWORD [ebp+8]      ; address of string to eax

        xor     ecx, ecx                ; initialize counter to zero

count_loop:
        mov     bl, [eax]               ; obtain the address of the 1st character
        cmp     bl, 0                   ; check the null value
        je      length_exit             ; exit if the null-character is reached
        inc     ecx                     ; increment counter
        inc     eax                     ; increment the address
        jmp     count_loop              ; start the loop again

length_exit:
        mov     eax, ecx                ; return ecx
        pop     ebp                     ;
        ret
```

First of all, is it a 32-bit or 64-bit program? If it is a 32-bit program why doesn't it have underscore character (`_`) in the name of the function?

I know that the following code-section is creating a stack-frame:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp                ; obtain the address of the
mov     eax, DWORD [ebp+8]      ; address of string to eax
```

but, why do we need to *save* `ebp`? Why can't we just write the following? :

```
 move eax, DWORD [esp+8]
```

And, why do we need the type-casting here?

I also need a memory layout of this program to understand the stack mechanism. I have found many pictures in the Internet, but I am not sure which one would be the appropriate one to represent this program.

Comment: Do you mean `mov eax, DWORD [esp+4]` (instead of `move eax, DWORD [esp+8]`)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I am not sure actually, but you probably get my question.

Comment: Well I assume you believe you can do away with `push ebp` `mov ebp, esp` (and the `pop ebp` at the bottom in favor of `mov eax, DWORD [esp+4]` . You can simplify it in this case, yes.

Comment: You **can** use `esp` just fine. Also, 32 bit has nothing to do with leading underscore, that's a feature of your toolchain. Linux doesn't typically use it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is a 32-bit program why doesn't it have underscore character (`_`) in the name of the function?

Because it's not Windows.

Linux/ELF systems don't use a leading `_` in any mode, regardless of CPU architecture.

> Why can't we just write the following?:  `move eax, DWORD [esp+8]`

**You can.  (If you spell `mov` correctly)**.  In fact, compilers default to using `-fomit-frame-pointer` when optimization is enabled, so they only use EBP as a frame pointer in functions with C99 variable-length arrays, or `alloca`.

32 and 64-bit mode allow ESP to be a base address for addressing modes, unlike in 16-bit mode where `[sp+2]` was *not* encodeable.

But remember that if you haven't pushed `ebp`, ESP is still pointing at the return address, so the first arg will be at `[esp+4]`.

> And, why do we need the type-casting here?

**You don't. The register operand implies the operand-size.**

(And it's not truly type-casting, just operand-size specifier.  It wouldn't do float-int conversion for you; you'd have to use `cvtss2si eax, [esp+4]` for that.)

You only *need* an operand-size specifier for mem,immediate instructions like `cmp dword [esp+4], 0`, which would be ambiguous between byte/word/dword operand-size.  Or for instructions like `movzx eax, byte [esp+4]` where the register operand *doesn't* imply a size for the memory operand.

Answer (score 0):

The reason stems from the encoding scheme of the instructions.
The *Table 2.2* from *Section 2.1.5* of the Intel Manual shows the possible combinations.

It shows that the (possible) encoding of the `ESP` register is used to indicate that a *SIB* byte (instruction extension byte) follows:

> The [--][--] nomenclature means a SIB follows the ModR/M byte.

So essentially the encoding for the `ESP` register is reused for encoding an extra instruction byte, the `SIB` byte.

In the *SIB* byte, the instruction encoding for `[ESP]` is also an exception. Look at *Table 2.3*.